# UnMarshalling content-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded using Jaxb2Marshaller throws error "Content is not allowed in prolog"

Tags: java, spring, rest, unmarshalling

I am trying to setup a rest service which handles request of content-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded. I am currently using Jaxb2Marshaller for unmarshalling the request. However while unmarshalling, it is throwing error "[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog.]".

I checked the xml request as string. It is in url-encoded form as:   %3C%3Fxml+version=%221.0%22+encoding%3D%22UTF-8%22+standalone%3D%22yes%22%3F%3E%3Cxrsi%.

It seems this encoded xml string request is causing the error. Is there any way to decode the request first than unmarshall?

Below is my context setting:

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="100000000" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="xstreamMarshaller" class="org.springframework.oxm.xstream.XStreamMarshaller">
        <property name="autodetectAnnotations" value="true" />
        <!-- Set some properties to make the outputted xml look nicer -->
    </bean>

    <mvc:annotation-driven>
        <mvc:message-converters>
            <!-- Configure the XStream message converter -->
            <bean class="org.springframework.http.converter.xml.MarshallingHttpMessageConverter">
                <property name="marshaller" ref="jaxbMarshaller2" />
                <property name="unmarshaller" ref="jaxbMarshaller2" />

                <property name="supportedMediaTypes">
                    <list>
                        <bean class="org.springframework.http.MediaType">
                            <constructor-arg index="0" value="application" />
                            <constructor-arg index="1" value="xml" />
                        </bean>
                        <bean class="org.springframework.http.MediaType">
                            <constructor-arg index="0" value="application" />
                            <constructor-arg index="1" value="x-www-form-urlencoded" />
                        </bean>
                    </list>
                </property>
            </bean>
        </mvc:message-converters>
    </mvc:annotation-driven>

    <bean id="jaxbMarshaller2" class="org.springframework.oxm.jaxb.Jaxb2Marshaller">

        <property name="classesToBeBound">
            <list>
                <value>com.auto.server.schema.ReceiveRequest</value>
                <value>com.auto.server.schema.ReceiveReply</value>

            </list>

        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean name="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">

        <property name="ignoreAcceptHeader" value="true" />
        <property name="favorParameter" value="true" />
        <property name="favorPathExtension" value="true" />
        <!-- if no content type is specified, return json. -->
        <property name="defaultContentType" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" />

        <property name="mediaTypes">
            <map>
                <entry key="xml" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" />
            </map>
        </property>
        <property name="defaultViews">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.xml.MarshallingView">
                    <constructor-arg ref="jaxbMarshaller" />
                    <property name="modelKey" value="responseObject" />
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- REST API controllers -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.auto.server.schema" />

Here is the controller part

@ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/heartbeat", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = { "content-type=application/x-www-form-urlencoded" }, consumes = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8")
    public Object heartBeat(@RequestBody ReceiveRequest request) {

        ReceiveReply reply = new ReceiveReply();        
        return reply;
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand why you want to use Jaxb to map form data? Seems like a weird requirement! Instead of forcing JAXB to understand form encoded data, just receive the form values in a POJO that maps to the form.

Comment: Actually, this implementation is form client. Client will send a rest call application-x-www-form-urlencoded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are always going to get data in URL-encoded style i.e `content-type="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`

Then you can simply decode that in your bean when you receive it through following code :

```
String decodedString = java.net.URLDecoder( inputString, "UTF-8" );
```